# R S3 class: Decide between overwriting vs appending the class name of the class attribute

Tags: r, r-s3

I want to create an S3 class. How do I decide which way of setting the class attribute is the right one (since it makes a difference)?

**1) Overwrite the class attribute**

```
object <- data.frame(field1 = "a", field2 = 2)
class(object)
# [1] "data.frame"
class(object) <- "MyClass"    # set the class by overwriting the existing one
class(object)
# [1] "MyClass"
```

**2) Append the class attribute**

I could also append the class name (at the beginning or end):

```
object2 <- data.frame(field1 = "a", field2 = 2)
class(object2) <- append(class(object2), "MyClass")
class(object2)
# [1] "data.frame"    "MyClass"

object3 <- data.frame(field1 = "a", field2 = 2)
class(object3) <- append("MyClass", class(object3))
class(object3)
# [1] "MyClass"    "data.frame"
```

I know that appending the class name at the beginning vs. at the end potentially changes the function that is called (from `?class`):

> When a generic function fun is applied to an object with class
>   attribute c("first", "second"), the system searches for a function
>   called fun.first and, if it finds it, applies it to the object. If no
>   such function is found, a function called fun.second is tried. If no
>   class name produces a suitable function, the function fun.default is
>   used (if it exists).

**E. g. if I define an overloaded function it is not always called:**

```
print.MyClass <- function(x) { print("printing MyClass") }

print(object)
# [1] "printing MyClass"

print(object2)
#   field1 field2
# 1      a      2

print(object3)
# [1] "printing MyClass"
```

**So my question is: How do I decide how to set the class name (which [other] criteria I have to consider)?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With reference to data.frame:

- **Overwriting** If you replace the class name with your own name then you must define your own methods for each generic that could be called with it unless the default method of that generic is ok.  If your class is completely different than the data frame then this is what you want.  This would be, for example, in the case that data.frame methods cannot be used on your objects.
- **Prepending** If you prepend your class name to the class vector then when a generic is called with an object having your new class name then the generic will first look to see if you defined a method for it and if not it will call the data.frame method.  This is what you want if you want to override certain functionality of data frame but make use of other functionality. For example, in the tibble package, the class vector for a tibble object is `c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")` and in the data.table package the class vector of a data.table object is `c("data.table", "data.frame")`
- **Appending** Normally you don't want to place your class after the existing class.  If you did then it would only get called if there were no data.frame method.

Comment: THX:-) So it looks like that option one (overwrite) is for completly new classes while **option 2 (prepending) is useful to "inherit" all functions from a base/parent class** until you overload it.