# double NextMethod() in r

Tags: r, oop, inheritance, methods

I am having problems how to make the following code work. In particular what should I have in the place of '???' to obtain the result c(4,7,1)

```
letter<- function()
{
  x<- numeric(0)
  class(x)<- append(class(x), "letter")
  return(x)
}


a<- function()
{
   obj<- letter()
   class(obj)<- append(class(obj),"a")
   return(obj)
}

aa<- function()
{
   obj<- a()
   class(obj)<- append(class(obj),"aa")
   return(obj)
}

met<- function(obj, ...)
{
   UseMethod("met", obj)
}

met.letter<- function(obj, ???)
{
  NextMethod(???)
}

met.a<- function(obj, ???)
{
   x<-4
   z<-1
   NextMethod(???)
}

met.aa<- function(obj, ???)
{
  y=y+1
  return(c(x,y,z))
}

aaobj<- aa()

met(aaobj, y=6)
# to return c(4,7,1)
```

I can not understand how to pass arguments to the next method, when they are created in the current method, and I don't want to pass these arguments to the call to the method.

Comment: You can find a good introduction into S3 (and S4) classes here: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s3.html - OOP is not intuitive in R IMHO

Comment: BTW: You should put your class name at the beginning (not the end) of the `class` attribute. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/45175988

Comment: Can you please describe the intention behind your code (which OO principles your are going to implement)?

Comment: What do you mean with the dots ("...") in the `met` function?

Comment: I have class 'letter', which has subclass 'a' and possible subclass 'b' which for the moment is not important. Then I have a subclasses 'aa' and 'ab' of subclass 'a'.

Comment: Then I want a method that does some things common to class 'a' , but when NextMethod reaches class 'aa' or 'ab' it does two different things.  In the 'met.a'  there should be variables that are created and passed to 'met.aa' or 'met.ab'. In the example above 'x' and 'z' .But these variables must not be arguments in the call 'met(aaobj, y)'

Comment: After a lot of trial and error I obtained ssometing, but I am not sure about the logic behind this:

Comment: `met.letter<- function(obj, y, ...)  
{  
  NextMethod()  
}`

Comment: `met.a<- function(obj, y,x=0,...)
{
  x=x+1
  NextMethod()
}`

Comment: `met.aa<- function(obj, x=x, y, z=0)
{
  x<-4;
  z<-1;
  return(c(x,y,z))
}`

Comment: `aaobj<- aa();
met(aaobj, y=6)`

Comment: I am still confused: if the class hierarchy is letter <- a <- aa and you have the same (!) method `met` than the signature may not be different for one of the implementation. Also: `NextMethod` shall  call the function of a parent class (not of child class as you wrote in the comment "when NextMethod reaches class 'aa' ").

Comment: *"'x' and 'z'  ... these variables must not be arguments in the call 'met(aaobj, y)"*: If you call a method of an object and cannot pass the variables as arguments, how shall this work? The only option then is to store the values in class attributes of the object (with "attributes" I do mean OO-attributes of a class, NOT R attributes!). And if the class does not offer attributes for these values you can only use the existing attribute "x" by using it as vector (appending the values). Confusing: The class attribute of `letter` is names `x`, the variable in `met.a` too

Answer (score 0):

Here is an OO-alike version of your code with "log output" to indicate how it works:

```
# Class Hierarchy:
# AA inherits from A inherits from letter (= base class)

# Constructors ---------------------------------------------
letter <- function()
{
  x <- numeric(0)  # this shall be an class attribute
  class(x) <- append("letter", class(x))
  return(x)
}

a <- function()   # class "a" inherits from class "letter"
{
  obj <- letter()
  class(obj) <- append("a", class(obj))  # attach the specialized class first!
  return(obj)
}


aa <- function()    # class "aa" inherits from class "a"
{
  obj <- a()
  class(obj) <- append("aa", class(obj))
  return(obj)
}

# Class methods -------------------------------------------

# This is a function in the base class "letter" that is inherited in the sub classes
# so that every sub class can provide its own implementation (polymorphism).
# To register such a generic function (= function call dispatching to class-specific functions/methods)
# "UseMethod" is called
met <- function(obj, x)  # met = method?!
{
  UseMethod("met", obj)    # "dispatch": Call the first existing function of pattern "met.<class>"
  # Code after this line will never be executed due to calling "UseMethod"
  print("met")
}

met.aa <- function(obj, x)
{
  print("met.aa - starting")
  x = x + 1
  NextMethod("met", obj)  # as last code in the function: Returns the return value of this function!
  # Do not add code after "NextMethod" or you will get the output of this code as return value
  # instead of the return value of NextMethod!
  # print("met.aa - leaving")
}

met.a <- function(obj, x)
{
  print("met.a - starting")
  x <- c(4, x, 1)
  res <- NextMethod("met", obj) # , c(4, x, 1))
  print("met.a - leaving")  #
  return(res)
}

met.letter<- function(obj, x)   # x may be a vector!
{
  print("met.letter starting")
  # "append" looses the attributes (class!) so we reassign it
  # a() should better return a list with one vector element as "class attribute"
  # so that the attributes keep untouched if changing the "class attribute"
  old.classes <- class(obj)
  obj <- append(obj, x)
  class(obj) <- old.classes
  # no NextMethod() call - it is the base class (= root!)
  return(obj)
}

met.default <- function(obj, x) {
  warning("met.default: not implemented")
}

aaobj <- aa()
aaobj
# numeric(0)
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "aa"      "a"       "letter"  "numeric"

aaobj <- met(aaobj, 6)
aaobj
# [1] 4 7 1
```

Note: You should put your class name at the beginning (not the end) of the class attribute so that if you call a generic method the most specialized class method will be found and called first.

For details see http://www.stackoverflow.com/q/45175988